# $_POST não funciona?

Tags: php

Preciso criar outra página para o `if(isset($_POST['n'])){$n= $_POST['n'];}`
verifica se o usuário digitou algum valor e submeteu no form

Formulário

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Divisão</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="POST" action="calculo.php">
            <h1> Digite um numero: </h1> <input type="text" name="n"/>
            <input type="submit" value="confirmar"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Página *calculo.php*

```
<?php
class controlador{
    private $n;

    function getN(){
        return $this -> n;
    }
    function setN(){
        $this -> n = $n;
    }

if(isset($_POST['n'])){//verifica se o usuario digitou algum valor e submeteu no form.
    $n= $_POST['n'];

    // DIVISIVEL POR 10
    if ($n %  10 ==  0)
    {
        echo $n . " é divisível por 10 =  " . $n/10 . "<br>";}
    else
    {
        echo $n . " nao divisível por 10 <br>";
    }

    //DIVISIVEL POR 5
    if ($n %  5 ==  0)
    {
        echo $n . " é divisível por 5 =  " . $n/5 . "<br>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo $n . " nao divisível por 5 <br>";
    }
    // DIVISIVEL POR 2
    if ($n %  2 ==  0)
    {
        echo $n . " é divisível por 2 =  " . $n/2 . "<br>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo $n . " nao divisível por 2 <br>";
    }

}
else echo "informe um numero"; //quando não digitar nada
?>
```

Comment: Há alguns erros na sua classe `controlador` é importante a leitura da documentação: [Classes e Objetos](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.php). Sua classe tem uma condição perdida dentro dela ou foi apenas na hora de colocar aqui? e ainda falta fechar `class controlador {
// código
}`

Comment: Vixi eu já não estou entendo mais nada. Condição perdida? é que o professor pediu para usar os métodos de orientação a objetos, no execício.

Comment: Não era para a condição `if(isset($_POST['n'])){` estar dentro de um método ? Quando você envia o `form` retorna algum erro na página ?

Comment: Parece me mesmo que se baralhou na construção da classe como o @NoobSaibot indicou. O ideal é rever mesmo a materia de classes e objetos e voltar mais tarde quando já souber minimamente bem como essas partes funcionam.

Comment: o `$this` e o `->` têm que ser junto `$this->`  e o `n` dentro do `if`teria que ser `$this->n` Para tudo isso não precisaria ser orientado a objetos